# Prove some fact of $G_\delta $ and $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are dense in the complete space $X$, so what I want to prove is that only one of them can be $F_\sigma$ in $X$.

My attempt is the following:

Let's suppose that $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are $F_{\sigma}$ then we get that

$$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$

$$X \setminus A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$$

where $E_{n}$ and $B_n$ are closed for all $n$, but we can write:

$$X \setminus A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} 
X\setminus E_n$$

with $X\setminus E_n$ open, then

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} 
X\setminus E_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n $$

therefore we get that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ is closed but $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} 
X\setminus E_n$ is open.

The thing is that I am not using the completeness of the space $X$ and the last part I think is not correct (I think I can't ensure that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ is closed and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} 
X\setminus E_n$ is open )

Can someone help me to fix the problems (If I have of course :)) or provide another proof please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need only to use the Baire category: As

$$X = \bigcup_n E_n \sqcup \bigcup_k B_k$$

and $X$ is complete, then one of them ($E_n$ or $B_k$) are not nowhere dense, which means that some of $E_n$ or $B_k$ contains a nonempty open set. If, for example, this closed set is $E_n$, then $A$ contains an nonempty open set and $X\setminus A$ cannot be dense. Similar for $B_k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but can you explain the last part please? and the notation between the union sets is union right?

Comment: @user162343: The $\sqcup$ sigifies disjoint union: the sets $\bigcup_nE_n$ and $\bigcup_kB_k$ are disjoint sets whose union is $X$. And the word *closed* in the last sentence is supposed to be *open*: one of the sets $E_n$ or $B_n$ must contain a non-empty open set. If it’s an $E_n$, then $X\setminus A$ is not dense, and if it’s a $B_n$, then $A$ is not dense.

Comment: @user162343 : The wording was quite vague. I edit the answer, hope it is better now.