# Proving that a set is nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset X$ be dense in $X$. If $E$ is closed in $X$ and $E\cap A = \emptyset$, then I want to prove that $E$ is nowhere dense.

My attempt:

We will prove that $X \setminus \overline{E}=X \setminus E$ is dense in $X$. So we first note that since $A$ is dense in $X$ we have that for all $\epsilon >0$ and $x \in X$, $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \not= \emptyset$.
Now we will prove that $A \subset X\setminus E$, and this is beause if we have $x \in A$ but $x \notin X\setminus E$  this implies that $x \in E \Rightarrow E\cap A \not= \emptyset $, so $A \subset X \setminus E$, but the first part of the proof imply that $\forall \epsilon >0 $ and $x \in X$ $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap X \setminus E  \not= \emptyset$ and this means that $X \setminus E$ is dense and therefore $E$ is nowhere dense.

Then my question is, Am I right in my proof? or what do I have to fix or change.

My definition of nowhere dense:

A set $A$ is nowhere dense If the set $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is dense.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: nowhere dense means it's closure has an empty interior. which is not equivalent to not dense

Comment: Moreover, the fact that $X\setminus E$ is dense does not imply that $E$ is not dense.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is dense but $\mathbb{Q}$ is also dense.

Comment: I have edited my post with my definition of nowhere dense :)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof that $X\setminus E$ is dense in $X$ is correct (or at least seems correct to me), although it could use a bit more spacing and punctuation for the sake of the reader.

*Now*, the last step, when you say "$X\setminus E$ is dense, *hence* $E$ is not dense", may require a bit more care and justification -- the statement is false.... $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but so is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. And you're asked to prove nowhere density, not "not density."

**Edit:** Following the clarification in the question and the subsequent discussion in the comments below (copied here):

> OK, [so] your definition *is* equivalent to the standard one. Anyway, for your proof to be "correct", replace in the last sentence "is not dense" by "is nowhere dense" (otherwise, your conclusion does not match what you aim at proving): *"$X\setminus E$ is dense, and therefore $X\setminus \bar{E}$ is dense as $E=\bar{E}$: by definition, this means $E$ is nowhere dense."*

Comment: Following up: if you are confused about what you need to prove: you have to show that the interior of the adherence of $E$ is empty, i.e. $\mathring{\bar{E}}=\emptyset$. Now, since $E=\bar{E}$ as $E$ is closed, this amounts to showing that $\mathring{E}=\emptyset$.

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Comment: For your new definition, your proof seems correct (as written at the beginning of my answer). I'm quite puzzled by this definition, however -- where does it come from? (It is not the standard one -- is it equivalent to it?)

Comment: Well, we have taken that definition from I think a Folland's book :), so I think now my question is clear, and I am right in my proof right?

Comment: OK, thinking a bit more your definition *is* equivalent to the standard one. Anyway, for your proof to be "correct", replace in the last sentence "is not dense" by "is nowhere dense" (otherwise, your conclusion does not match what you aim at proving): $X\setminus E$ is dense, and therefore $X\setminus \bar{E}$ is dense: by definition, this means $E$ is nowhere dense."

Comment: Thanks :), can you help me witth this one please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460430/prove-some-fact-of-g-delta-and-f-sigma-sets ? Thnks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, let $x\in E$ be interior point. then $B(x,r)$ for some $r$ positive,  is contained in $E$ and hence open and hence must intersect $A$ which is contradiction

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 1):

Since E is closed, it is nowhere dense if its interior is empty. If A doesn't intersect E, so E is in the complement of A (which has empty interior: the complement of a dense set has no interiro). So E is insid a set with no interior, it has no interior.

Comment: Can you help me with the last question I posted ?

Comment: I am sorry, which question?

Comment: This one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727546/proving-that-the-tangent-bundle-is-independent :)

Comment: I am so sorry but I have no idea...this is  differential geometry...

Comment: Jajajaja ok :) thanks anyway :), do you know of someone that can help ?

Comment: You are very welcome. No. I would send the question to an author of a text book on the subject. Or a professor in a university who works on the subject. You can see the departments of different universities on line. Good luck.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious mistake in your reasoning, i.e. assuming that $E$ is nowhere dense if $X\setminus E$ is dense. The counter example to that claim is that both $\mathbb Q^c$ and $\mathbb Q$, the irrational and rational, are dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ denote the interior of the closure of $E$.

Since $E$ is
closed it coincides with its closure so $U$ is also the interior
of $E$.

Then $U$ is an *open subset* of $E$.

If $U\neq\varnothing$
then $A\cap U\neq\varnothing$ since $A$ is dense and $U$ is open.

This contradicts
$A\cap E=\varnothing$ since $U\subseteq E$, so we conclude that $U=\varnothing$.

Proved
is now that $E$ is nowhere dense (i.e. the interior of its closure
is empty).

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Comment: the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: And then what do you think about my proof :)?

Comment: Your proof is okay, but - as Clement remarks - is not optimal when it comes to efficiency, elegance and clarity.

Comment: jajaja right :) I know that but I am a beginner in this :), but then there is nothing to fix right?, and another favor, can you help me with this one please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460430/prove-some-fact-of-g-delta-and-f-sigma-sets ? Thnks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If E is closed, it is nowhere dense if its interior is empty. Now, since E doesn't intersect A, so it is in the complement of A, which has no interior (the complement of a dense set has no interior and vice versa). If E is inside a set with no interior, it has no interior.

Comment: Can you help me with the last question I have posted ? Thanks in advance (differential geometry)