# Proving that the tangent space is independent

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a sub-algebra  of continuous functions on $U$ for each $U$ and there exists $f \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f(p)=1$ and its support is inside $U$ for each $p \in U$.

Then for a manifold $M$ (with this I mean a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras locally isomorphic to the algebra of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$) the tangent space $T_p M$ is the space of $\mathbb{R}$-derivations at $p$. By a derivation I mean a linear function

$$l: \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that it satisfies the Leibniz rule, this is:

$$l(f·g)=l(f)g(p)+f(p)l(g).$$

But the thing is that I know that this definition must be independent of the $U$ I take, and I can't figure out a proof for this, I want to use this result if $f$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $p$ and $l$ is a derivation then $l(f)=0$. Because I think the goal is to prove that if $T_p M(U_1)$ and $T_p M(U_2)$ are tangent bundles for $M$ then

$$T_p M(U_1) \simeq T_p M(U_2)$$

Since what we are doing is the following, we take all the continuous functions $f:U_p^{1} \to \mathbb{R}$ then this defines $\mathcal{F}(U_p^{1})$, now with this we take all the derivations $l: \mathcal{F}(U_p^{1}) \to \mathbb{R}$ and with these ones we define $T_p M$ right?

Can someone help me to prove this please?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

The restriction to a smaller open set $U$ gives an isomorphism at the level of the tangent space the way you define it because when you introduce local coordinates $(u^1,\ldots, u^n)$ one shows easily that the space is spanned by the set of derivations defined by the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}$, and these will be present no matter how small your $U$ is.

Comment: Just a second to check this right?

Comment: Can you explain your answer more please? Because I don't get it :) thanks

Comment: A proof of the isomorphism of the space of derivations with the set of linear combinations of partial derivatives can be found in chapter 12, section 12.10 of the course notes [here](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/egreglong.pdf).

Comment: Right, but how do that helps with this issue? :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Your $T_1$ and $T_2$ are each isomorphic to the space spanned by partial derivatives. Therefore they are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that since $T_1$ and $T_2$ isomorphic to the span of partial derivatives then they are isomorphic so then the tangent space is independent of $U$ right?

Comment: Well I know that $T_p M$ has dimension $n$ no matter which $U$ we are taking then how do you conclude?

Comment: The commutative diagram involving the three spaces ($T_1$, $T_2$, and the one of partial derivatives) is commutative.  Does that do it for you?

Comment: Not quite, first of all, Is my assertion correct? I mean I have to prove that the two tangent spaces, with respect to different sets $U$ are isomorphic right?

Comment: I have edited my post so I hope that now is clear what I am defining and you can elaborate more with this ideas :)