# Show that $T_p \mathbb{R}^{n} $ naturally isomorphic to $T_0 \mathbb{R}^{n} $

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that if $\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf of smooth functions then

$$T_p \mathbb{R}^{n} \simeq T_0 \mathbb{R}^{n}$$

naturally, but I don't know how to proceed or argue this (I was thinking of using the push-forward map of derivations but I don't know how ). In fact I have read [this reference](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/peter.hochs/Tangent_spaces.pdf) (page 330) but I don't know if I can apply that here.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

> **Definitions**

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a sub-algebra  of continuous functions on $U$ for each $U$ and there exists $f \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f(p)=1$ and its support is inside $U$ for each $p \in U$.

Then for a manifold $M$ (with this I mean a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras locally isomorphic to the algebra of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$) the tangent space $T_p M$ is the space of $\mathbb{R}$-derivations at $p$. By a derivation I mean a linear function

$$l: \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that it satisfies the Leibniz rule, this is:

$$l(f·g)=l(f)g(p)+f(p)l(g).$$

Comment: You should be able to do the push-forward that you mention by applying a linear map that takes $0$ to $p$.  Then, show that a derivation at $0$ maps to a derivation at $p$.

Comment: Ok Can you perform that explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Presumably you're looking for something like this: If $U_{0}$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $0$, then $U_{p} := p + U_{0}$ is a neighborhood of $p$, and there is an isomorphism of algebras defined by sending $f_{0}:U_{0} \to \Reals$ to the function $f_{p}$ defined by $f_{p}(x) = f_{0}(x - p)$.

Comment: Right, and then how do you use the push-forward?

Comment: If $l_{0}$ is a derivation on $\mathcal{F}(U_{0})$, define a derivation $l_{p}$ on $\mathcal{F}(U_{p})$ by $l_{p}(f_{p}) = l_{0}(f_{0})$ for each $f_{p}$ in $\mathcal{F}(U_{p})$.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that the derivation is $x \to x-p$? well, $f_0$ compose with that right?

Comment: Sort of: A derivation maps functions (or germs, depending on your viewpoint) to numbers; functions near $0$ are "naturally identified" with functions near $p$. To "differentiate" a function $f_{p}$ defined near $p$, identify it with its "avatar" $f_{0}$ (defined near $0$), and apply a derivation at $0$. This defines a mapping $l_{p}:\mathcal{F}(U_{p}) \to \Reals$ that satisfies the conditions of a derivation. (Details left to you. :)

Comment: Well before analyzing the above, can you help me with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727546/proving-that-the-tangent-space-is-independent ?

Comment: How do you Know that $f_0 \circ (x-p) $ is an isomorphism since $f_0$ can be any continuous function so we don't know if it has inverse :) right ?

Comment: The isomorphism isn't $f_{0}$ itself, but the association $f_{0} \leftrightarrow f_{p}$. Note that you can recover $f_{0}$ from $f_{p}$ via $f_{0}(x) = f_{p}(x + p)$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part :)

Comment: The isomorphism in question associates $f_{p} \in \mathcal{F}(U_{p})$ to $f_{0} \in \mathcal{F}(U_{0})$. The formulas $f_{p}(x) = f_{0}(x - p)$ and $f_{0}(x) = f_{p}(x + p)$ _define_ each function in terms of the other, and thereby define (function by function) an isomorphism between the stated algebras. (In case an example helps, consider smooth functions on, say, $U_{0} = (-1, 1)$ and $U_{p} = (3, 5)$, and think about how you'd map a function on one interval to a function on the other by precomposing with a suitable translation.)

Comment: By this you are saying that $f_p=f_0(x-p)$ and $f_0=f_p(x+p)$ are the function and the inverse right? so indeed we have a isomorphism, am I correct?